# Set vertical spacing of custom new environments

Tags: spacing, captions, listings, environments, minted

I defined a `code` environment in which `minted` environments are put in order to span in multiple pages. The problem is that captions are too close to the text next to the `code` frames. How can I increase that and apply it by default?

Here is a MRE

```
\documentclass[corpo=11pt,twoside,tipotesi=magistrale,greek]{toptesi}

\usepackage[a-2b]{pdfx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
\setminted{
    linenos,
    breaklines,
    breakanywhere,
    % framesep=4mm,
    % bgcolor=lbg,
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{%
\renewcommand{\fcolorbox}[4][]{#4}}

\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Listato}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9

\lipsum[1]

\begin{code}
    \begin{minted}{json}
    {
        "@context": [
            "https://www.w3.org/ns/did/v1"
        ],
        "id": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN",
        "created": "2021-10-25T18:43:48.074918",
        "authenticationMethod": {
            "id": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN#keys-1",
            "type": "RsaVerificationKey2018",
            "controller": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN",
            "publicKeyPem": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0n12lUROi9VVZoFDan1O...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        },
        "assertionMethod": {
            "id": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN#keys-2",
            "type": "RsaVerificationKey2018",
            "controller": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN",
            "publicKeyPem": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzYhPXrHwvGE9bq8hTzA1...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        },
        "services": []
    }
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Esempio di DID document in formato JSON.}
    \label{lst:did-doc}
\end{code}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The space I'm referring to is highlighted in the following image

[image]

I'd also like if what I'm trying to achieve is good from the typographic perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{\par\addvspace{13pt plus2pt minus1pt}}` to add some stretchable space at the end of the enviroment.

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `\newfloat` rather than `\newenvironment`.

```
\documentclass[corpo=11pt,twoside,tipotesi=magistrale,greek]{toptesi}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage[a-2b]{pdfx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
\setminted{
    linenos,
    breaklines,
    breakanywhere,
    % framesep=40mm,
    % bgcolor=lbg,
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\renewcommand{\fcolorbox}[4][]{#4}}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lml,
  listname={Elenco dei listati},
  name=Listato,
  placement=htp,
]{code}
\captionsetup[code]{
   position=below,
   aboveskip=0pt,
%   belowskip=6pt,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{code}
    \begin{minted}{json}
    {
        "@context": [
            "https://www.w3.org/ns/did/v1"
        ],
        "id": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN",
        "created": "2021-10-25T18:43:48.074918",
        "authenticationMethod": {
            "id": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN#keys-1",
            "type": "RsaVerificationKey2018",
            "controller": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN",
            "publicKeyPem": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0n12lUROi9VVZoFDan1O...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        },
        "assertionMethod": {
            "id": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN#keys-2",
            "type": "RsaVerificationKey2018",
            "controller": "did:ott:POLYARUCUR9ANFHKACMBZIBONMMTDXBRYG9CCGRZTOE9QLDOQKFVTNAOWSPXGIPPQDNQDPFWVT9KSERQN",
            "publicKeyPem": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzYhPXrHwvGE9bq8hTzA1...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        },
        "services": []
    }
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Esempio di DID document in formato JSON.}
    \label{lst:did-doc}
\end{code}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember that if you write in Italian, `fontenc` with the `T1` option is mandatory. Also `fix-cm` is recommended, so you don't get a wealth of font warnings.

Remove the `\errorcontextlines=9` line or, if you really want it, put it at the very beginning. In any case, remove it from examples here.

Comment: If I use a float environment the `code` will not be spanned across pages